# Split sales over months and display them in a table

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array `$sales` which has a structure like below:

```
array(627) (

[0] => array(4) (
    [id]=> (int) 1
    [name] => (string) Tesla
    [total]=> (string) 24
    [month] => (string) 4
  )

[1] => array(4) (
    [id]=> (int) 1
    [name] => (string) Tesla
    [total]=> (string) 18
    [month] => (string) 5


[2] => array(4) (
    [id]=> (int) 1
    [name] => (string) Tesla
    [total]=> (string) 18
    [month] => (string) 6

[3] => array(4) (
    [id]=> (int) 2
    [name] => (string) Audi
    [total]=> (string) 16
    [month] => (string) 4
  )

[4] => array(4) (
    [id]=> (int) 2
    [name] => (string) Audi
    [total]=> (string) 18
    [month] => (string) 5
```

What it does is it stores sales information for each type of car and for each month. Some of the months don't have sales so they are blank.
What I want to do is to loop through each type of car and display sales like below:

```
Car      Jan. Feb. Mar. Apr. May. Jun. Jul, Aug. Sept. Oct. Nov. Dec
Tesla    0    0    0    24   18   18   0    0     0    0    0     0
Audi     0    0    0    16   18    0   0    0     0    0    0     0
```

I would appreciate some help on the way to approach this as I don't have a clear idea. It would be great if you could point me out in the right direction.

Comment: What kind of output do you want ? Html ?

Comment: @Joulss yes, I need to display it in a table.

Comment: Use something like LINQ for PHP: https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo It should make things very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a basic enough taks to be solved with some foreach loops:

```
$result = [];
foreach($sales as $sale) {
    if(!isset($result[$sale['name']]))
       $result[$sale['name']] = [];

    if(!isset($result[$sale['name']][$sale['month']]))
       $result[$sale['name']][$sale['month']] = $sale['total'];
    else
       $result[$sale['name']][$sale['month']] += $sale['total'];
}

foreach($result as $model => $months) {
    for($month = 0; $month < 12; $month++) { // assuming that January is 0
        $total = ($months[$month] ?? 0);
    }
}
```

See the operator [??](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Thank you for your input. This doesn't solve however setting to 0 the months for which there are no sales, there's my struggle.

Comment: It is a bit complicated, The $result array gives me only the name of the car and total sales. It would be great if the result array would be name, month and then the total sales. I'm missing the month in the first loop. Sorry, I'm quite new to this and it's difficult to follow.

Comment: The result variable can be thought of as an array of arrays. It's sort of like a matrix, but not quite, as the rows have variable lengths. The rows of the matrix are the models, and the columns are the months. And the values are the total sales. So, result[model][month] shows you the total sales for the model in that month if it has any

Comment: Thank you again, I'm sorry but I am not able to make this work, to display it in the table like above. With al this loops I don't know how to proceed..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is stupid, but I would use a SQL database instead of arrays. You have more flexibility and can let the server do the math.